# Django app on IIS8 using FastCGI; FastCGI crashing

Tags: python, django, iis, fastcgi

I've tried to set everything up according to this tut: http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/06/27/running-django-under-windows-with-iis-using-fcgi/

I've taken the steps in settings.py to debug the fastcgi stuff, but I suspect it's not even getting to that point. The site returns the 500 error:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Python27\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

I suppose my next step is finding out A) what things might cause fastcgi to crash in this case, or B) how I can get a more useful error message out of its crashing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: Oh man that was awhile ago... This was resolved, but I think my wife cracked the case and I can't remember exactly what was done; but I think it had something to do with python errors crashing fastCGI. There was an error that wasn't present on our local machines, but something was wrong in the production environment. I believe we changed it to "development mode" or some such and fixed the code. I'm not too familiar with Python unfortunately, so take my comment with a grain of salt.